# Please wait while jenkins is getting ready to work

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-operation

I tried installing Jenkins as installable file and also as an app inside Tomcat server. But for both I am not able to get Jenkins up and running. It is stuck at initial page saying 'Please wait while Jenkins is getting ready to work; Your browser will reload automatically when Jenkins is ready.' I tried checking tomcat logs for error when deployed in tomcat, but there is no log as well.

I had searched for possible issues and found this occurs if Java is missing. So I have verified my Java installation and JAVA_HOME environment variable. Still not able to get Jenkins up. Attached screenshot.[Jenkins not starting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COCZC.png)
Please point out to possible issue.